# Django database tables made but cannot import models from it

Tags: python, django, apache

I am configuring django on CentOS. i have made a project using command
`django-admin.py startproject mysite`

then i made an app using commad

```
python manage.py startapp polls
```

in models i have two classes the code is given below which i have taken form dajgo's official site

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

i have django.wsgi placed in /var/www folder. its code is

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

i have also placed the mysite directory in /var/www/ folder but to no avail

Now when i try to import models in python

```
from polls import Poll, Choice
```

it give errors such as

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "polls/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
```

Does anybody know whats the issue???

Comment: in manage.py, have you imported the project/apps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.edit your import statement to look like this:

```
from polls.models import Poll, Choice
```

2.be happy.

Comment: cant be happy that what i got

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named polls.models

Comment: hmm that sounds odd.  check the django docs: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api
test in a shell:
>>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice   # Import the model classes we just wrote.

this should work if you have your app created properly and you actually have a models.py file that is populated

Comment: i was trying this in shell not in any IDE...
do you think th pythin version could be doing some problem
i have 2.6 and 2.7 both installed
but when i write python 2.6  interpreter gets spawned

Comment: from your project folder, make sure you are entering the shell with 'python manage.py shell'.  if you just type 'python' - then it will not be able to import anything related to your project.  having 2.6 or 2.7 will not matter.